# Website hyperlink on mobile not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have this website that works perfectly  on a desktop, but weirdly, when opening on a mobile device (iPhones, iPads, etc), the hyperlink [ENTER SITE] does not function. I have checked everywhere and cannot seem find the error or any solution. All of the other pages of this website work except for this page (index.html). Another thing that could help out is that the index page uses a different CSS than the other pages.

Website in question: http://www.thebadgethemovie.com

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what happens when it's touched?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the css `display` property of your anchor element to `block`.